# what can i do to access only a specific table

Tags: javascript, php

I 'm working at with XAMPP server at my home pc.My files are in xampp/htdocs/marfo  I am trying to fetch some records in a booking database lying on xampp\mysql\data\marfo. Althought  i can read all others tables of the same database (using different files at the same directory) this specific table gives me this error "***Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/marfo/booking.php. (Reason: CORS request not http).***"

the code in js is:

```
function readres() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responceText != "NoResults") {
                reservarray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                // function to set whole site for this language


            } else { return "Bad thing !!! Something went wrong .........." }

        } else { return "Didn't found anything malaka.........." }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "booking.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

and the code at PHP file:

````
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'marfo';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$counter = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output reservations
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $reservarray = array(
            "datefrom" . $counter => $row["datefrom"], "dateto" . $counter => $row["dateto"], "name" . $counter => $row["name"]
        );
        $counter = $counter + 1;
    }
    echo json_encode($reservarray);
} else {
    echo 'No results';
}

$conn->close();```

any help appreciated....
````

Comment: You've accessed the page runnig this request directly from the file system, use a `http` address to enter the page, then there will be no CORS problems.

Comment: check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: i did use http. no error message but still doesn;t response anything. keep staying in readyState  1 with no error.....:-(

Comment: Typo: `responceText`. Another typo: `NoResults` will never match `echo 'No results'; `

Comment: Are you sure about `readyState` staying at 1? That tells, that you never called `xmlhttp.send()`.

Comment: Quentin thank you, you are right. But still this is not causing the problem......

Comment: The problem is that at all similar situations with the same code from the same directories i access all the 6 rest tables of this database.

Comment: The request works as it is (when the page is opened with http://), but you'd never see it working (as it is in the question), the return value from a callback will go to the bitspace. What ever you do with the server response, you've to do it in the callback, or in another function you call from the callback. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: THANK YOU ALL. PROBLEM SOLVED WITH xmlhttp.open("GET", "http ://localhost/marfo/book.php", true);  AND DUE TO  https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled